# ERROR AS :duplicate alias name in developer console (Group BY)

Tags: soql

Why do i get this ERROR as :duplicate alias name in developer console.

When i use the Soql Query as :

```
SELECT gmod__product__r.name, gmod__opportunity__c, SUM(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c, SUM(gmod__Quantity__c) gmod__Qunatity__c, COUNT(id) Quantity 
FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c
GROUP BY gmod__product__r.name, gmod__opportunity__c
```

It displays the product name and the opportunity record id's.

When i Use this SOQL query:

```
SELECT gmod__product__r.name , gmod__opportunity__r.name, SUM(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c, SUM(gmod__Quantity__c) gmod__Qunatity__c, COUNT(id) Quantity 
FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c
GROUP BY gmod__product__r.name, gmod__opportunity__r.name
```

Throws an Error as:

> duplicate alias name.

I want the product name and opportunity name to get displayed.

Any Suggestion plz.

Comment: Might be helpful: https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_groupby_alias.htm

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Abandoned

Answer (score 1):

Use Alias, below query should work.

```
SELECT gmod__product__r.name gmod__product__r_name , gmod__opportunity__r.name gmod__opportunity__r_name, SUM(gmod__Amount__c) gmod__Amount__c, SUM(gmod__Quantity__c) gmod__Qunatity__c, COUNT(id) Quantity 
FROM gmod__Opportunity_Forecast__c
GROUP BY gmod__product__r.name, gmod__opportunity__r.name
```